# JAXB globalBinding for anonymous enums

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to generate the java classes using JAXB for the below XSD.

And I had to use the below bindings file to generate enum classes for any simple element derived from xs:string and that has enumeration facets.
However it always generates a String instead...

(Note: I cannot change the XSD)

[see typeSafeEnumBase here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148515)

**bindings.xjb file:**

```
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" typesafeEnumBase="xs:string"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**test.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" 
     xmlns="http://www.example.com" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="ElementName">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_2"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element ref="ElementName"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**command:**

```
xjc -verbose test.xsd -b bindings.xjb
```

Generated java class:

[Root.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIpv4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must add following bindings

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='ElementName']/xs:simpleType">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="ElementName" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
But I was trying to handle it at a very generic level. Hence the description "**... for any simple element derived from xs:string and that has enumeration facets ...**"

Comment: I guess that you can't .. because your simpleType is anonymous :(